# AWS - EC2 and RDS in different regions is very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I'm currently in Sydney and I do have the following scenario:

- 1 RDS on N. Virginia.
- 1 EC2 on Sydney
- 1 EC2 on N. Virginia

I need this to redundation, and this is the simplified scenario.

When my app on EC2 sydney connection to RDS on N. Virgnia, it takes almost 2.5 seconds to give me the result. We can think: *Ok, that's the latency.*

BUT, when I send the request to EC2 N. Virginia, I get the result in less then 500ms.

Why there is a slow connection when you access RDS from outside the region?

I mean: I can experience this slow connection when I'm running the application on my computer too. But when the application is in the same region that RDS, works quickier that on my own computer.

Comment: What's the real question here? You seem to understand that there's latency between Sydney and Virginia, do you understand what causes that latency and why it would be lower between machines that are in the same building or at worst a few miles apart?

Comment: "Why there is a slow connection when you access RDS from outside the region?" Because it is literally traveling half way around the world and back. How is that not entirely obvious? Your question is more of a physics question than a software development question. How is your setup "redundant" anyway if Virginia going down means that your database would go down? You need to look into cross-region database replication if you actually want a redundant infrastructure.

Comment: @MarkB... I always try to make my questions dumb-proof. Because people like you always tries to reply, but not give a actual answer. For example: I wrote: This is the SIMPLIFIED SCNEARIO because I know that some one would point that a system with a unique point of failure is not redundant. But you could stick to it? For sure not, you have to point it out. If you want a repliy about the "obvious", please just read the entire question again. Thanks for now.

Comment: @John I posted a comment, not an answer. My comment, and others, is directed at the fact the the only portion of your post that appears to be a question, has an extremely obvious answer: It is the expected latency of such a long distance network connection. You say some other stuff in your question that makes it sound like you have some reason to believe that this shouldn't be the expected latency, but none of that part of your question makes any sense. The last paragraph in particular makes no sense to me at all. Perhaps you should expand on that and provide some details?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you request to RDS requires multiple roundtrips to complete. I.e. at first your EC2 instance requests something to RDS, then something else based on the first request etc. Without seeing your database code, it's hard to say exactly what might be the cause of that.

You say then when you talk to the remote EC2 instance, instead, you get the response in less than 500 ms. That suggests that setting up a TCP connection and sending a single request with reply is 500 ms. Based on that, my guess is that your database connection requires at least 5x back and forth traffic.

There is no additional penalty with RDS in terms of using it out of region, but most database protocols are not optimized for high latency conditions. You might be much better off setting up a read replica in Sydney.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect the RDS using public-facing network, then it might be slow. AWS launched [cross region VPC peering](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/announcing-support-for-inter-region-vpc-peering/), please peer all the region's VPC (make sure there will not be any IP conflict) and try to connect using private connections.